# How to understand the meaning of this sentence with 2 "yorokobi" (“悦び” /“喜び”) and もうかがえる (mou kagaeru ??) <O>

Tags: grammar, meaning, kanji, manga, japanese-to-english

**When reading ,I'm confused by this sentence ,using 2 "yorokobi" (“悦び” /“喜び”) and もうかがえる ? (The writer's using only katakana here, so I'm not sure if I understood the meaning correctly ).
Much thanks if anyone can help me find its correct meaning o/**

Context : MC is commenting (in his mind) about a mysterious woman who's suddenly appears next to his bed at night ,after looked at her face/eyes and hear she speaks to him :

すると女の人の瞳により“悦び”の色が妖しく混じる。​
**この……妖しい“悦び”と、どこか“無垢”な様子もうかがえる“喜び”が入り混じったこの言葉。​**

**(my guess : "In her words mixed with pleasure/joy ,somewhere I can also see the air of pure/innocent peeks out" ?)**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your guess is mostly correct while your parsing is wrong. も is the particle "also" and うかがえる is 伺える "can see", potential form of [うかがう](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/%E4%BC%BA%E3%81%86/#jn-18016). So どこか“無垢”な様子もうかがえる“喜び” is *joy in which you can also see innocence somehow*

As for the second sentence, it is a long noun phrase where この言葉 is modified by the preceding この....混じった. With A=この....妖しい"悦び" and B=どこか..."喜び", it is *Those words where A and B are mixed*. (Or the starting この can be understood as a duplicate of この of the last この言葉 and A=妖しい“悦び”.)

On the difference of 喜び/悦び, usually in the modern usage, the former means neutrally "joy/happiness" whereas the latter often has the connotation of ecstasy. So, for example, おもちゃをもらった子供が悦んでいる usually looks odd. I've heard this kind of distinction is generally/historically not well founded, though.